# Better way to run DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Current situation is I have my machine (C:) starting script/macro "Start" which opens up access db on shared drive (Q:\Database.accdb) and runs numerous specifications to update table (`DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport`) and runs numerous specifications from frontend (Q:\Dashboard.accdb) to produce "reports" (`DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport`). I can't seem to get both to execute 100% of time without various errors popping up.

Currently I have managed to get the first set of `DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport`s to run properly but I keep getting the following error when I attempt to launch the next set:

Run time error '462'

The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.

I want to say the issue is I am getting some sort of lock but I am opening a whole new file? Any help?

```
Public Function Start()

Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "Q:\Database.accdb"
appAccess.Application.Visible = True

DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "CoolUploadToDB1"
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "CoolUploadToDB2"

KillProcess "MSACCESS.exe"
ExportReports

End Function

Public Function ExportReports()

Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "Q:\Dashboard.accdb"
appAccess.Application.Visible = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

#Consistently works up until here:
#Gives error: Run time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.

DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "ExportCoolReport1"
CoolFuncToAnnoySomePeopleWithReport "OneGuyITotallyHate@coolcompany.com"

appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
appAccess.Application.Quit
Set appAccess = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Function
```

Comment: If this is Excel VBA code, try `appAccess.DoCmd` so that the correct Access application is invoked.

Comment: My man, thank you. @YowE3K, your right it's referencing the associated importexports specs from the first opened access. Your comment is exactly what I need to load the next set of specs thanks!

Comment: I guess this question is answered, then. Tip: don't use `KillProcess "MSACCESS.exe"` when you can just use `accApp.Quit`. You can gently ask Access to quit, or you can murder Access and risk corrupting the database in doing so.

Comment: Thanks @ErikvonAsmuth I was hoping that would release the specs that were currently being stored and starting a new instance right after would load the new specs. I was wrong. The question is answered yes but I tried answering it on YowE3K's behalf but it didn't work